# How to group by column in LINQ?

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, datatable

I want to group a VB.NET DataTable by the Change Date column as represented in this Excel spreadsheet:

[image: Spreadsheet representation of DataTable]

So, the end result would look like this:

[image: End Result]

Currently, I'm trying to group the rows together by the following LINQ query:

```
Dim lQuery = From d In dtData Group d By key = "Change Date" Into Group _
               Select changeDate = key, testGroup = Group
```

The end goal is to create a new DataTable with the specified grouping.

UPDATE:  I feel like I made some progress with the following:

```
Dim tester = dtData.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(Function(row) New With { _
                                   Key .ChangeDate = row("Change Date")})

dtData = LINQToDataTable(tester)
```

I got the LINQToDataTable function from http://forums.asp.net/post/4469664.aspx because the CopyToDataTableMethod wasn't appearing.

This creates the following data table:

[image]

It's obviously grouping correctly, but it's not selecting the other columns. Any advice?

UPDATE:

So I took D Stanley's advice and modified my LINQ query to the following:

```
Dim lQuery = From d In dtData.AsEnumerable() _
             Group d By key = "Change Date" _
             Into test = Sum(d(2)), _
             test2 = Sum(d(3))
```

This code produced the following error on the Sum() functions:

[image: Sum() Error]

So, I tried to cast the row values to doubles, which compiled correctly, but obviously throws runtime exceptions when attempting to cast null values to a double:

```
Dim lQuery = From d In dtData.AsEnumerable() _
             Group d By key = "Change Date" _
             Into test = Sum(CDbl(d(2))), _
             test2 = Sum(CDbl(d(3)))
```

What should I pass to the Sum function so that it will compile correctly and run correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the *aggregations*:

```
Dim lQuery = From d In dtData 
             Group d By key = "Change Date"  
             Into 2008 = Sum(d.2008),
                  2009 = Sum(d.2009),
                  ... etc.
```

replacing `2008`, `2009`, etc. with whatever member names you use for those columns.

Comment: Thank you.  This makes sense.  Do I have to reference any libraries for the Sum() method to work correctly?  I'm getting several errors:  On `Into 2008` - `Group or identifier expected`, and `cannot resolve symbol` on both the Sum functions

Comment: Those variable names are not valid - you need to replace them with the proper column names (or use `d(n)` to reference the columns by their index).  I was going by what you had in your spreadsheet.

Comment: Great.  I suppose that this will become increasingly complex when I mention that there are null values in some of the year columns?  So when I attempt to sum them, it attempts to add DBNull, which doesn't work.  Is there any easy way to support nullable types?

Comment: Enumerable.Sum should skip over NULL values.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I wasn't sure what to pass to the Sum() function, as it wouldn't compile with the `d(n)`parameter (e.g. `Sum(d(3))`).  So I casted the row index value to a double, which obviously doesn't support casting NULL to double.  Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are trying to do?

```
Dim lQuery = From d In dtData Group d By key = d.changeDate Into Group _
           Select changeDate = key, testGroup = Group
```

Comment: Hmm. I think I tried something similar, but I gave it another go.  Visual Studio is complaining about the first `Group`.. `Type arguments cannot be inferred from the query.`